# If part of string matches populate specific value in other column/cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I am using googlesheets, and needs help with a formula for the below usecase.

if a number from column B matches the part of the number from column A then populate specific value in column C

for example: of value from column B  = 0000 matches partly in column A (its always last 4 to matches in column A) then populate APPLE in column C

[image]

Comment: Where does 'APPLE' come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting

```
=if(REGEXMATCH(A1,B1), "APPLE", "")
```

into cell `C1` will work, just make sure to change `"APPLE"` for whatever your text source is.

To have it go down the whole column automatically put this in `C1` instead:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(REGEXMATCH(A1:A,B1:B), F1:F, ""))
```

Assuming that column F has your strings you want to check:

[image]